# initialization in "while loop" or quit the program

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

so here i have a code and my problem is when i press 1 to quit the program i can type stop to quit the program but i want it to be like as soon as i press 1 i want to quit the program without typing stop. how should i fix it? because after press 1 and type something that is not "stop", it will start from the beginning

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String text = "";

    while (!text.equals("stop")) {
        System.out.println("\n(1) To quit this program, Press 1");
        int starter = scan.nextInt();

        switch (starter) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Type Stop to quit this program`");
                System.out.println("Bye");
                text = br.readLine();
                break;
        }
    }

    scan.close();

}
```

Comment: In you `case 1:` make text equal to `stop` instead of reading the text from the `BufferedReader`....

Comment: Because you are using readline to read the user input, which could not send the line as soon as you press `1`,  plus the code for `scan` is missing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `break`, use `return` which will make the method exit.

Comment: But the OP still needs to type `1` AND `stop`

Comment: @MadProgrammer, OP said "i want to quit the program without typing stop"

Comment: @BenjaminCheng That's my point. From what you answer reads, you want to replace `break` with `return`, which means the OP will still be prompted to enter "stop", which would then be completely ignored regardless as you've just returned anyway. Also, I'm old school, I was taught to have only one entry and one exit point in a method, adding `return` to the middle of the code can cause confusion to people who are trying to read the code IMHO

Answer (score 0):

In your `case` statement, when `starter` is equal to `1`, make `text` equal to `stop`....

```
switch (starter) {
    case 1:
        text = "stop";
        break;
}
```